# How to post to a form which has type="file"

Tags: c#, winforms

I can't seem to figure this out.

Using `HttpWebRequest`, how do you post a form which was one of the inputs as `type="file"`?

Usually when posting regular fields, I do something like this:

```
"username={0}&password={1}", username, password"
```

But I don't know what to put in the `type="file"` field.

Comment: Even if you're not looking to actually upload files, the accepted answer in the dupe post should give you what you want.

Comment: I'll second that, they answer there details all one needs to know about using multipart/form-data instead of url-encoded.

Comment: Yea, got it to work eventually.